# NestJS .env file doesn't get built

Tags: node.js, nestjs, dotenv

I'm using dotenv v8.2.0 in my NestJS project, and it has always worked in my production environment. I cloned the project on my new pc, made a .env file with the right variables in the root folder, but the .env file now doesn't get built into the dist folder.

The .env file:

```
databaseHost=database-di... 
databasePassword=a3^U...
```

The setup of my main.ts file (only relevant parts):

```
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import * as path from 'path';`

const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '..', '.env');
config({ path: ENV_FILE });
```

When I log the dotenv config function, i get the following:

```
{
  error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Jasper\***\dist\.env'
      at Object.openSync (fs.js:461:3)
      at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
      at Object.config (C:\Users\Jasper\***\node_modules\dotenv\lib\main.js:96:29)
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jasper\***\dist\src\main.js:21:22)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:32)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:14)
      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
      at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
    errno: -4058,
    syscall: 'open',
    code: 'ENOENT',
    path: 'C:\\Users\\Jasper\\***\\dist\\.env'
  }
```

When I look at the dist folder, the .env file does indeed not get ported over, while it used to always work. Logging the variables in the .env folder returns `undefined`.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `.env` file is not a Typescript or JavaScript file, and as such will not be moved by Typescript. You may be able to move it using the `assets` property of the `nest-cli.json`, but then you'll need to make sure to commit your `.env` file which is a bad practice. Instead, the `.env` file should be read from the project root (same level as `package.json`) and each environment should have its own `.env` file to keep the secrets secured.

Comment: All right thanks! I had no idea, since I'm rather new to TS & JS. I now configured it to pull them from the root folder and that does work. We work with Kubernetes Secrets to hold the secrets in the .env file for CI/CD, so no need to commit the file :)

Comment: Jay McDoniel I have a problem where my Config Service does not take into account what's in my .env file